# Agrandar un array usando sus propios elementos hasta nivelarlo al tamaño de otro

Tags: javascript, array

Quiero mejorar el siguiente algoritmo:

**¿Qué hace este codigo?**

Pretende nivelar los 2 arrays(que tengan el mismo tamaño).

**¿Cómo debe nivelar?**

Con sus mismos elementos hasta que sea `array2` del mismo tamaño que `array`

```js
var array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 1];
var array2 = [11, 12, 13];

var cp = array2.length;
var x = 0;

while (x < array.length) {
  for (var y = 0; y < cp; y++) {
    if (array2.length < array.length) {
      array2.push(array2[y]);
    }
  }
  x++;
}
console.log(array2);
```

¿Cómo puedo usar `reduce` o `filter` para reemplazar estas líneas?

```
while (x < array.length) {
      for (var y = 0; y < cp; y++) {
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Puedes crear un array temporal con el tamaño que los diferencia y rellenarlo con los mismos valores que el arreglo 2 con sus valores haciendo uso del módulo que representa el tamaño del arreglo 2 y el índice que está siendo recorrido en el nuevo arreglo antes de ser modificado.

```js
const arr1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 1];
let arr2 = [11, 12, 13];

const size = arr1.length - arr2.length;
const mod = arr2.length;

arr2 = [...arr2, ...Array(size).fill().map((_, i) => arr2[i % mod])];
    
console.log(arr2);
```

Comment: muy bien, pero creo que no entiendo muy bien, que es  ...arr2? y (_, i) ? porque pones 3 puntos, y underscore?

Comment: El underscore es simplemente un nombre para la variable que hace de valor, al no utilizar la variable y ser necesaria qué esté ahí para poder utilizar la siguiente que es el índice es común darle un nombre así haciendo entender que será ignorada. Los 3 puntos son el "Spread Operator", en este contexto lo que estoy haciendo es extraer los elementos del array creado haciendo qué [1,2,3] pase a 1,2,3.